Move DataGridView Column to Right
I created a Context Menu for a DataGridView is am using to manipulate data from various non-conforming Tab-delimited files. (Old financial stuff)
One of the functions I needed was the ability to move all columns to the right.
I tried to understand .Insert, .Add, and .Clone to no avail as the sharers are so far above me as coders.
Please take a look at this and give e some ideas for improvement because with long files the pause is traumatic.
        private void dgv_MoveColumnRight(DataGridView dgv, int cIndex)
        {
            dgv.ColumnCount = dgv.ColumnCount + 1;
            int cCount = dgv.ColumnCount - 2;
            if (dgv.RowCount <= 1) { return; }
            while (cCount >= cIndex)
            {
                dgv_CopyColumn(dgv, cCount);//showMe.Comment = "From: " + n1.ToString();
                dgv_PasteColumn(dgv, cCount + 1);
                //dgv.Rows[1].Cells[cCount].Value = "*";
                cCount--;
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            for (int n = 0; n < dgv.RowCount; n++)
            {
                dgv.Rows[n].Cells[cIndex].Value = " ";
            }
        }

        List<string> colData = new List<string>();
        private void dgv_CopyColumn(DataGridView dgv, int cIndex)   
        {
            colData.Clear();
            for (int n = 0; n < dgvStatement.RowCount; n++)
            {
                if(dgv.Rows[n].Cells[cIndex].Value != null)
                {
                    colData.Add(dgv.Rows[n].Cells[cIndex].Value.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    colData.Add(" ");
                }
                showMe.Comment = n.ToString() + "\t" + colData[n];
            }
        }

        private void dgv_PasteColumn(DataGridView dgv, int cIndex)  
        {
            if (colData.Count == 0) { return; }
            for (int n = 0; n < dgvStatement.RowCount; n++)
            {
                dgv.Rows[n].Cells[cIndex].Value = colData[n];
            }
        }

The final code will pass the list instead of having it exposed.
Thanks

Maybe it helps
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-change-the-order-of-columns-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Have you tried not updating the grid while you're doing the repainting?... In this example you might also have improved by creating a new column, sorting its position and cleaning up the "old" column
private void dgv_MoveColumnRight(DataGridView dgv, int cIndex)   {
    ....


    // Suspend visual refresh of the DataGridView
    dgv.SuspendLayout();

    //Create new column last
    dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());

    // Move columns
    for (int colIndex = dgv.ColumnCount - 2; colIndex >= cIndex; colIndex--)
    {
        MoveColumnData(dgv, colIndex, colIndex + 1);
    }

    // Clean "old" column
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dgv.RowCount; rowIndex++)
    {
        dgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[cIndex].Value = null;
    }

    // Perform DataGridView Visual Update
    dgv.ResumeLayout();
}

private void MoveColumnData(DataGridView dgv, int fromIndex, int toIndex)
{
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dgv.RowCount; rowIndex++)
    {
        dgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[toIndex].Value = dgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[fromIndex].Value;
    }
}

Good luck

I have not tried suspend. The Application.DoEvents was troubleshooting.
The display does pause while the process is going on, so I am not sure suspending is going o make a noticeable difference. Worth a try though.
The reason I back fill with spaces if cell is NULL is because otherwise I get a NULL error.
I was hoping for an internal functionality in .NET
